# Why does Firebase throw error even after using NPM install?

Tags: firebase, npm

When I run NPM Install, there seems no problem, but when I use Firebase deploy an error is still thrown.

This is when I run NPM install

```
xxxxxx-MacBook-Pro:Edzuki-Learning xxxx$ npm install
audited 375 packages in 3.733s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

And this is the error:

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'actions-on-google'
Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

And so the cycle repeats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often this is because of a lack of sufficient permissions. Go onto the package.json and add the line `"actions-on-google": "^2.0.0",` under the `"dependencies":` If this does not solve it, try to un then re-install NPM or simply update it